# Table Frames beyond simple lines

Tags: tables

Is there a possibility to create frames for tabulars, that go beyond a simple line?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
A & B\\
\hline
C & D\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

creates lines as a "frame", but these are indistinguishable from the lines that separate the rows and columns. I would like to have, for example thick lines for the frame. Or double lines that look good and not like the one I create like this

```
\begin{tabular}{||l|l||}
\hline \hline
A & B\\
\hline
C & D\\
\hline \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz) can help here

[image: screenshot]

Of course, because it's `tikz`, you can get much more adventurous with your affects if you want to.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikz\node[draw=red,thick,double,inner sep=1pt]{
\begin{tabular}{l|l}
A & B\\
\hline
C & D\\
\end{tabular}};

\end{document}
```

If you'd like to apply the idea to *every* `tabular`, then you could use the [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf), perhaps something like the following- note the gradient shading :)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\tikzpicture\node[draw=red,thick,double,inner sep=1pt,top color=blue,bottom color=yellow]\bgroup}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tabular}{\egroup;\endtikzpicture}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  A & B\\
  \hline
  C & D\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Perhaps you'd like `rounded corners`

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\tikzpicture\node[rounded corners=3pt,draw=red,thick,double,inner sep=1pt,top color=blue,bottom color=yellow]\bgroup}
```

[image]

You could even go completely crazy and surround the `tabular` in a `circle` or a `star`, but I'll leave that up to you :)

The possibilities are limited only by imagination- have fun, and check out the manual for more ideas and options.

Comment: Thanks, I got some nice frames from your examples. Although I dont think, that I need color at all in my tables! ;)

Comment: @Haatschii you're very welcome :) glad it helped!

Comment: With `inner sep=.3pt+\pgflinewidth`, `.3pt` being the half of `double distance` (initially `.6pt`), the outer lines just touch `tabular`'s lines instead of drawing over them.

Answer (score 9):

You could be interested in the features provided by the [`tabu`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabu) package: a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

{\arrayrulewidth=3pt
\begin {tabu}{|[5pt cyan!60!black]c|[5pt red!60!black] c|[5pt cyan!60!black]}
\taburulecolor{orange}
\hline
A & B \\
\hline
C & D \\
\hline
\end {tabu}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not everything that can be done, should be done.

Comment: @Aditya wise words, indeed!

Comment: I think this will work as well, maybe even more elegant. But I just completed it using cmhughes approach. Thanks nevertheless!

Answer (score 6):

Besides the TikZ solution where you can create very *interesting*  tables, there is the [`hhline`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hhline) package which is suited for *just*  tables.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{||l|l||}
    \hhline{#==#}
    A & B \\ \hhline{|--|}
    C & D \\ \hhline{#==#}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{||l|l||}
    \hhline{|t:==:t|}
    A & B \\ \hhline{||--||}
    C & D \\ \hhline{|b:==:b|}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package on some guidelines for creating good looking tables. In general, it is not a good idea to use vertical lines in tables. The booktabs package also provides `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule` commands for rules of different thickness.

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\toprule
A & B \\
\midrule
C & D \\
E & F \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know booktabs and use it most of the time. However in this case I am creating some kind of form sheet, that has to be filled out in printed form by other people. So I really want the vertical lines to make clear where to write. I don't think booktabs helps here.