# setting a tikzset which has draw inside as style of a \node

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I need to get different color edges for my rectangular nodes.

I found this question
[How do I set only one side of a tikz node's border color?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199968/how-do-i-set-only-one-side-of-a-tikz-nodes-border-color#)

The \tikzset mentioned in the answer has input arguments and I don't know how to set them when used with \node.

I have tried to remove the arguments and set the styles but the all I get is  a xetex in infinite loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzset{%
mynode/.style ={
       \draw[thick,red,line cap=butt,shorten <= -0.5\pgflinewidth,shorten >= 0.5\pgflinewidth] (a.south west) |- (a.north east);
       \draw[thick,blue,line cap=butt,shorten <= 0.5\pgflinewidth,shorten >= -0.5\pgflinewidth] (a.south west) -| (a.north east);

}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{main}=[rectangle, minimum width = 30mm,minimum height = 50mm, thick, draw =black!80, node distance = 6mm]

    \node[main] (m)  {$A$ };
    \node[mynode] [right=of m] (x2) { $R$}; %commenting this line out with eliminate the infinite loop
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: It would be very helpful if you provide (non) working minimal example (MWE) which we can copy in own computers and compile it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you looking for something like this

[image]

than the following MWE can be of help:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\tikzset{%
    mynode/.style = {rectangle, 
    path picture={%
    \draw[thick,red]    (\ppbb.south west) |- (\ppbb.north east);
    \draw[thick,blue]   (\ppbb.south west) -| (\ppbb.north east);
                },% end of path picture
                 },
        }% end of tikzset
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x2) [mynode] {$R$};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**edit:**
or slightly different appearance

[image]

obtained with the following (slightly modified) code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\newcommand\ppbb{path picture bounding box}
\tikzset{%
    myline/.style={draw=#1, thick, shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth},
    mynode/.style = {rectangle, 
    path picture={%
    \draw[myline=red]    (\ppbb.south west) |- (\ppbb.north east);
    \draw[myline=blue]   (\ppbb.north east) |- (\ppbb.south west);
                },% end of path picture
                 },
        }% end of tikzset
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (x2) [mynode] {$R$};    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: would it be at all possible to pass arguments in \node?

Comment: @saiedVanguard, sorry, I do not understand you. In the first solution all arguments are in definition of it style (except definition os `\ppbb`), in second is style for border lines defined separately because with this is code for node style definition concise and  clear. If you like to have all this in definition of `mynode` style, you can replace `\ppbb` with `path picture bounding box` and `myline=<color>` with `<color>,thick, shorten <=0.5\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: @saiedVanguard You can use `#1` to represent the argument in the definition of `mynode` and then say `\node [mynode={<list of options>};`. Is that what you mean? You are already giving `\node` arguments! (Or as close as it comes to doing that, anyway, in TikZ.)

Comment: @cfr I meant an actual line of code that would pass some arguments.
the <> and list is a bit vague.

Comment: @saiedVanguard ??

Comment: How do you specify a list in latex? could you give an actual line of code that would work with the \tikzset in the question I referred to in my question?

Comment: This one I mean http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199968/how-do-i-set-only-one-side-of-a-tikz-nodes-border-color#